# php - get second row until last row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Using while loop, i can get all the result in the table and echo it into a html table.

But, i want to skip the first row, and echo the result starting from second row.
How can i do that?

This is my code.

```
$sql2="select * from table where year = '2015' and month = '2' order by month desc";
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
echo '<table>';
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>'.$row2['acc_sth_date'].'</th>';
echo '<th>'.$row2['acc_sth_med_ori'].'</th>';
echo '<th>'.$row2['acc_sth_med_new'].'</th>';
echo '<th>'.$row2['acc_sth_operator'].'</th>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Help me please master. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in two ways.

1. You could use `LIMIT` statement in your sql query :

   `$sql2="select * from table where year = '2015' and month = '2' order by month desc LIMIT 1,100";`

   1 = Start at the 2nd row

   100 = Returns a maximum of 100 rows
2. Add a condition in your `while` loop :

> ```
> $firstRow = true;
> while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
> {
>      if (true === $firstRow)   
>      {
>            $firstRow = false;
>            continue;
>      }
>
>
>       // ... Rest of your code ... 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a variable that is tested and set to true to not allow skipping next time:

```
$FirstRun=true;    
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
  if ($FirstRun){
    $FirstRun = false;
  }else {
  echo '<tr>';
   echo '<th>'.$row2['acc_sth_date'].'</th>';
   echo '<th>'.$row2['acc_sth_med_ori'].'</th>';
   echo '<th>'.$row2['acc_sth_med_new'].'</th>';
   echo '<th>'.$row2['acc_sth_operator'].'</th>';
   echo '</tr>';
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3513410 glad to know, don't forget to accept my answer ;P

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
$sql2="select * from table where year = '2015' and month = '2' order by month desc";
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
$row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
$count = count($row2);
$i = 1;
echo '<table>';
while(i>=$count)
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row2[i]['acc_sth_date'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row2[i]['acc_sth_med_ori'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row2[i]['acc_sth_med_new'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row2[i]['acc_sth_operator'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
$i++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

It will display all rows except the first row.